# Display json as html in react dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to display an html response from an axios call in a pop up window in react.
Here is what I'm doing.  I first make the call in my component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const previewTemplate = getPreviewTemplate(props.customFields);
    previewTemplate.then(htmlResponse => {
      setHtmlTemplate(htmlResponse.data);
    });
  }, [props.customFields])
```

The method for that is

```
const getPreviewTemplate = async (template) => {
  let result;
  try {
    const headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    result = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/template-preview',
    {html: template.previewHtml}, headers
    )
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
        return error.response
      } else if(error.request) {
        return error.request
      }
    }
  return result;
}
```

This runs and returns an html layout.  I then attempt to have it pop up when I click a button.
(All the onChange etc has been removed for brevity)

```
  <Popup
  >
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlTemplate}} />
  </Popup>
```

The HTML code appears in the pop with the error:

```
   Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '/Volumes/OGX/Code/itsyoo-build/server/views/layouts/
<style media="screen,print">
    #g-handyman---patch-shape-box ,
    #g-handyman---patch-shape-box .g-artboard {
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #g-handyman---patch-shape-box p {
        margin:0;
    }
.. etc
```

What am I doing wrong?  My expected behavior would be for the code to appear in html format not like a visible string as it is appearing.

Comment: I think it's back-end API problem. It response the error to you. React is just prints the result faithfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would expect your code to work, it's certainly not the "React" way of doing things. The React team would most certainly be pushing you towards [dynamic `import`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import), so when the popup opens the JavaScript bundle for that component would be fetched and rendered, all within Reactland.

But I'm sure you asked the question because dynamic imports are outside of the scope of what is possible for your project. It looks to me that you are hitting a server error if you're seeing `ENAMETOOLONG`. Please check that the request is actually returning a `200` and that there aren't any issues with your server.

Comment: Will check this.  The reason I didn't go all react is because I've read it was best to do as much on the backend as I could as opposed to trying to run it all client side.  Thank you! @Dave Lunny

Comment: While I agree that it's generally better to pick one end of the stack to do heavy lifting on, I'm not sure that where you're drawing that line is correct. Consider looking into doing server-side rendering via `ReactDOMServer`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup

Comment: Yes sir will check that out, THANK YOU!  @Dave Lunny